# Derivative of a differential

Tags: differential-topology

Let $\rho_t$ be the one-parameter flow associated to a vector field $v$ on a manifold $M$.

What is $\frac{d}{dt} d_p\rho_t$?

Intuitively,
$$
\frac{d}{dt} d_p\rho_t = d_p \frac{d}{dt} \rho_t = d_p (v \circ  \rho_t) = d_{\rho_t(p)}v \cdot d_p \rho_t.
$$

However, this seems wrong as $v$ is a vector field and $dv$ appears.

Any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $M$ is not Euclidean space, please identify the spaces the quantities live in.

Comment: If $\rho_t$ is a family of diffeomorphisms $M\to M$, then $d\rho_t$ should be a family of diffeomorphisms $TM\to TM$, and hence its time derivative should be a vector field on $TM$, no?

Comment: Oh but $d_p\rho_t$ is a map $T_pM\to T_{\rho_t(p)}M$. How do you differentiate this family of maps with respect to $t$? each has a different codomain.

Comment: Unless you mean the derivative $d/dt$ to act at the end, after $d_p\rho$ has already acted on a tantent vector at $p$ and the result has acted on a smooth function?

Comment: In what context did you find this object?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I'm actually after $\frac{d}{dt} [(d\rho_t)^{-1} (w\circ \rho_t)] ,$ where $w$ is another vector field on $M$.

Comment: @mathandchess and what object do you expect it to be? $(d\rho_t)^{-1}(w\circ\rho_t)$ is a vector field for each $t$. So $\frac{d}{dt}[(d\rho_t)^{-1}(w\circ\rho_t)]$ is also a vector field for each $t$. For $t=0$, you get the definition of the Lie derivative $L_vw$. Is that what you want?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I guess I'm trying to show directly that this expression is equivalent to the definition via the commutator of vector fields.